# Insert jQuery UI Dialog Modal Form data into mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, user-interface

I'm using the jQuery UI Dialog for the registration of new users on my website. The dialog works fine. However, when I submit the form the AJAX call isn't doing anything. I've searched the web for a while but I can't find a working solution. This is my code at the moment:

```
var username=$("#username").val();
var password=$("#password").val();
var checkpassword=$("#checkpassword").val();
var email=$("#email").val();
var user_level=$("#user_level").val();
var date_created=$("#date_created").val();

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 500,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Registreren": function() {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                bValid = bValid && checkLength( username, "username", 3, 16 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 4, 16 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( checkpassword, "checkpassword", 4, 16 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( user_level, "user_level", 0, 2 );
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( username, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "error" );
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, "error");
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "error" );
                bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( checkpassword, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "error" );

            if ( bValid ) {
                $.post({
                url: 'register.php',
                data: 
                        {  
                            username: username,
                            password: password,
                            checkpassword: checkpassword,
                            email: email,
                            user_level: user_level,
                            date_created: date_created
                        }//end data
                })//end AJAX post
           }//End if
        }//End function
    }//end buttons
});//end dialog
```

My form is just a simple HTML input form with the specified ID's

Ex input username:

```
<form name="registeracc" id="registeracc" action="register.php" method="post">
<input required type="text" id="username" name="username" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
</form>
```

I've found several "fixes" for this problem on the web, but they dont seem to work for me.

Ex:

```
data: $('#registeracc :input').serialize(),
error: function(xml, status, error) {
$('#registeracc').html('<p>???</p>');
```

Comment: `data: $('#registeracc').serialize(),` will serialize the form into name|value pairs. The returned string needs to be used in the right way but I can't see enough of your code to advise.

Comment: Have you verified if the button click code is even getting called? After you verify that, watch the ajax request in Firebug or Chrome dev tools to see what/what isn't being posted.

Comment: It got stuck on some validation lines, after removing them it didn't call anything

Comment: Take out the `if ( bValid ) {` and see if that changes anything. Also check your error console.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't solve my original problem but it solved something else that was bugging me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer which solved my problem:

```
$.post({
url: 'register.php',
data: 
{  
   username: username,
   password: password,
   checkpassword: checkpassword,
   email: email,
   user_level: user_level,
   date_created: date_created
}
```

Should be:

```
$.post("register.php", $("#registeracc").serialize());
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but according to [jQuery API Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) try

```
$.post(
    'register.php',
    {  
        username: username,
        password: password,
        checkpassword: checkpassword,
        email: email,
        user_level: user_level,
        date_created: date_created
    }//end data
)//end AJAX post
```

Comment: +1 although this doesn't answer the question, it still fixes a problem that you would run into later. To elaborate on this answer: OPs `.post()` syntax is wrong, it takes a list of arguments instead of an object with properties (unlike $.ajax).